# supplying water for all houses of a city with either a well or pipe

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, dijkstras-algorithm

Consider $n$ houses in a city which each house's water can be supplied with either a well or pipes from other houses. Constructing a well in a house $i$ costs $w_i$ and connecting a pipe from house $i$ to $j$ costs $c(i,j)$.

The question is to find an algorithm to find the minimum cost to provide water to all houses.

My approach is to use Dijkstra's algorithm to answer it. The weight of each node is $w_i$ (its well cost). Enter each node's weight into a priority queue. and then it just starts from the minimum of the priority queue, and doing Dijkstra's normally.

I think it's wrong. Can anyone guide me a little?

By the way, my algorithm is using Dijkstra's as you see -- but I think it should use a minimum spanning tree. However, I have some difficulty finding a way to take the weight of each node (cost of a well) into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V = \{s, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ and there is an edge $(v_i, v_j)$ of weight $c(i,j)$ for all distinct (unordered) pairs $i,j$ with $1 \le i \le n$. Moreover, for each $i=1,\dots,n$, add the edge $(s, v_i)$ of weight $w_i$ .

Let $T = (V, E_T)$ be a minimum spanning tree of $G$. Build a pipe from house $i$ to house $j$ iff $(v_i, v_j) \in E_T$. Build a well on house $i$ iff $(s, v_i) \in E_T$. The cost of building these pipes/wells is exactly the weight of $T$. To see that this is optimal notice that any solution that costs $c$ that provide water to all houses implies the existence of spanning tree of $G$ with weight at most $c$.

Comment: so it's like doing kruskal on starting node s, where s is an imaginary node having edge to all n nodes with weight equal to wi? 
and can you please elaborate about the proving part?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it this way (but you can actually use any MST algorithm). What's unclear about the proof of optimality? There exists a spanning tree of total weight at most $c$ if and only if there exists a solution to your problem of total cost at most $c$, therefore the weight of a MST coincides with the minimum cost among all possible solutions, i.e., the cost of an optimal solution (and the answer shows ho to recover the optimal solution itself from the MST).

Comment: i think i got it. thanks. i'm new to algorithms and just feel so dumb and overwhelmed by everything :')